# Get Process PID With PsLookupProcessByProcessId

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, wdk

```
#include<Ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <WinDef.h>

void SampleUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    DbgPrint("Sample driver Unload called\n");
}

extern "C"
NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = SampleUnload;

    DbgPrint("Sample driver Load called\n");

    PEPROCESS EP = NULL;
    if (PsLookupProcessByProcessId(::PsGetCurrentProcessId(), &EP) == STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
        DbgPrint("Can't get the eprocess");
    }
    else {
        DbgPrint("Its working");
    }
    LPBYTE pUpi = ((LPBYTE)EP) + 0x440;
    PVOID UniqueProcessId = *((PVOID*)pUpi);

    DbgPrint("Test Test Test!");
    DbgPrint((CHAR*)UniqueProcessId);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hello everyone,
I am trying to print out the pid of the driver as an exercise.
When I am starting the driver he is working but in the 30 line he doesn't print anything and in all the others he does!
I want to print out the pid of the process using EPROCESS.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What is `((LPBYTE)EP) + 0x440` supposed to do?

Comment: I know how to print. all my others prints works fine. and ((LPBYTE)EP) + 0x440 is the address to the PID.

Comment: `UniqueProcessId == PsGetCurrentProcessId()` and `EP== PsGetCurrentProcess` in your case. so unclear what you try todo. also you must call `ObDereferenceObject(EP)` if `PsLookupProcessByProcessId` return `>= 0` and you can not access `EP` if api return `< 0` but you not check result at all.

Comment: *Get Process PID With PsLookupProcessByProcessId* -but `PsLookupProcessByProcessId` take Process PID as input. so you must already have it for use this api. strange tittle.

Comment: I know that I have the process id but as an exercise I am trying to get him with PsLookupProcessByProcessId and EPROCESS.

Comment: `DbgPrint((CHAR*)UniqueProcessId);` error in any case. strange that no bsod. `DbgPrint("pid=%p\n",UniqueProcessId);` must be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in the 30 line he doesn't print anything

you try say that

```
DbgPrint((CHAR*)UniqueProcessId);
```

doesn't print anything.

[`DbgPrint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprint) accept pointer to the format **string** to print in first argument. but `(CHAR*)UniqueProcessId` not a string, even if you cast it to `(CHAR*)`. if `UniqueProcessId` valid value - it small number, usually less than `0x10000`, and memory access to this location (`DbgPrint` will try read this "string") must cause exception/bsod. but because use hard-coded offset (*0x440*) from `EPROCESS` always wrong - you read not process *UniqueProcessId* but some random data, which in your case accidentally point to valid memory. valid code for print must be like

```
DbgPrint("UniqueProcessId=%p\n",UniqueProcessId);
```

also all your code before this line, not have sense and contains critical errors

Comment: Thank you it worked. Another question how can I use the function FindWindowA in my driver?  Because There is now function like this in ntddk.h

Comment: @tantan `FindWindowA` in driver not good idea. however you can try call [*NtUserFindWindowEx*](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory/+/refs/heads/master/wininc/ntuser.h#1896) from *win32kfull.sys*

Comment: What do I need to include for using this function?

Comment: @tantan nothing. you need declare this api itself. it undocumented. and get it address at run-time from *win32kfull.sys* (if not found - in *win32k.sys*)

Comment: Thank you very much man you are the best! So how can I get handle to a process if I have his pid? I tried to use ZwOpenProcess but it doesn't like OpenProcess in user mode.

Comment: @tantan  - if you need process handle - use `NtOpenProcess` (if you know that previous mode is kernel) or `ZwOpenProcess`. of course if you need not current process handle